# What to do if node repair wasn't ran within GCGraceSeconds?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I don't believe any of my nodes have been down for an extended period of time, so I believe all of my deletes should have been replicated throughout all of them.  However, I keep seeing recommendations as normal maintenance to run node repair within GCGraceSeconds.  I don't believe node repair has ever been ran on my cluster (I inherited it a few months ago).  Do I have anything to worry about?  Will I have zombie data if I run node repair even if I haven't had any nodes down for an extended time?

My main question is - what can I do to get out of this state so I can start routinely running nodetool repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra has no 'normal' deletes as relational databases have. When you delete something Cassandra just adds some record which marking data as deleted, named 'tombstone'. Even if all of your tombstones are properly replicated they're still lives in your files, and can affect performance and even make some deleted records be 'alive' again.

In general, you need to run 'nodetool repair' on every node of your cluster regularly.

You can check details in the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html).

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with how tombstones work.  I need to reword my question to ask how I can fix this, I guess.  I don't know what the implications will be if I do a nodetool repair right in the current state that I am in.

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly you are safe until all your nodes are up - but you can't guarantee that forever, right?
And IIRC having repair is always safer than not having repair...

Comment: So in my case where all my nodes have pretty much always been up except for a few rolling restarts, I should be safe to start using repair regularly?

Comment: Simple:
1. Not having repairs - safe only if all nodes are up (rolling restart counts)
2. Having repairs - safe in any case.
Repair is a burden, though, but necessary for your data integrity in general.